# Loading WPF UI dynamically

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

In my recent project I have to populate a WPF window dynamically based on the option selected in a combo box. For example if option A is selected then one window is populated and if option b is selected then another will populate.How to do that using MVVM.

Just to elaborate . In that dropdown I have three option one for Basic Authentication,One for OAUTH authentication and another for NoAuth. So based on the option selected in dropdown the UI will populate. Basically I want a templating like thing based on the data.

Comment: This question is way to broad. Go down to more specific detail on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

why are you relating this question to MVVM? is it because your combobox is not on the same view as the window you want to populate(still not good enough reason).

lets first answer the case that the combobox is in the same view(no viewmodel needed here).
you just need to use data trigger + element name

```
<ComboBox x:Name="authSelector" >
        <ComboBoxItem >Basic</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>OAUTH</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>NoAuth</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=authSelector,Path=SelectionBoxItem}" Value="Basic">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource basicTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=authSelector,Path=SelectionBoxItem}" Value="OAUTH">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OAUTHTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=authSelector,Path=SelectionBoxItem}" Value="NoAuth">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource noAuthTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

here are the data templates used here

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="basicTemplate" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="basicTemplate"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="OAUTHTemplate" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="OAUTH Template"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="noAuthTemplate" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="noAuth Template"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

if your combobox is not on the same view , and you want to use the view model to get the selected item then create property in the view model called SelectedAuthType and use that one in the data trigger 
instead of this in the data trigger

```
ElementName=authSelector,Path=SelectionBoxItem
```

like this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedAuthType }" Value="Basic">
```